# Android In-App billing: catch “You already have a pending order for this item”

Tags: android, in-app-billing

If a user tries to buy something twice, Android Market returns an error “You already have a pending order for this item”. I can handle this situation in application?

Answer (score 0):

From Android developer site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service

> Important: If a user purchases a managed item, you must prevent the
>   user from purchasing the item again while the original transaction is
>   pending. If a user attempts to purchase a managed item twice, and the
>   first transaction is still pending, Android Market will display an
>   error to the user; however, Android Market will not send an error to
>   your application notifying you that the second purchase request was
>   canceled. This might cause your application to get stuck in a pending
>   state while it waits for an IN_APP_NOTIFY message for the second
>   purchase request.